# How to correct 404"message:"city not found" open weather api

Tags: javascript, api

Novice programmer here trying to make a simple app using api's.  So far I am using open weather map's api, and google geocoder.  I've got it set up so the user can enter a city, state, country, or even continent, and it should respond with the temperature and description.  Nothing too fancy.  The problem is when the user enters a city or state that is misspelled, my app breaks and the server crashes.  This has even happened on countries like Laos - spelled correctly but still getting the same error.  I am using and ejs file to display the results. Here is some code:

```
 {"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}

 TypeError: /Users/jamesmolnar/Desktop/NewApps/weather/views/results.ejs:5
 3| <h3>Here are the results:</h3>
 4| <p>
 5|     <% data.weather.forEach(function(result) { %>
 6|         <%= console.log(data.weather) %>
 7|         <%= result.description %>
 8| <% }) %>

Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
My app.js file:

 // require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const request = require("request");


app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.render("index");
});

app.get("/results", (req, res) => {
let query = req.query.search;
let weatherApiKey = "0a79f1c8132aac82c5c086a570df5224";

let weatherUrl =
 "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
 query +
 "&appid=" +
 weatherApiKey;
request(weatherUrl, (err, response, body) => {
 if (!err) {
   let data = JSON.parse(body);
   console.log(body);
   res.render("results", { data: data });
 } else {
   console.log(err);
 }
});

let location = req.query.search;
let geoCodeApiKey = "AIzaSyBrxDkJD5NFSQqKFbc5axWn0sGPg0bRYn8";
let geocodeMapUrl =
 "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
 location +
 "&key=" +
 geoCodeApiKey;
request(geocodeMapUrl, (err, response, body) => {
 if (!err) {
   let mapData = JSON.parse(body);
   console.log(body);
 res.render("results", { mapData: mapData });
 } else {
   console.log(err);
 }
});
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log("Weather App is listening on PORT:", PORT);
});




my results.ejs file
<%- include ("./partials/header") %>

<h3>Here are the results:</h3>
<p>
 <% data.weather.forEach(function(result) { %>
     <%= console.log(data.weather) %>
     <%= result.description %>
<% }) %>
<% let tempInFahrenheit = (data.main.temp * 9/5) - 459.67; %>
<%=Math.floor(tempInFahrenheit)%> degrees outside.
</p>
<div id="map"></div>
<a href="/">Back</a>

<%- include ("./partials/footer") %>
```

Comment: Can you check the documentation of such API whether they offers options a for avoid misspellings? - I would check whether ths is possible or, for a temporal solution, once you get a 404 error, handle the error accrodingly.

Answer (score 0):

The app is crashing because your template cannot generate the `forEach` statement on the undefined `result` variable.

A real simple fix is to wrap that particular template inside the `if` conditions.

```
<%- include ("./partials/header") %>

<h3>Here are the results:</h3>
<p>
<% if (result && data) { %>
  <% data.weather.forEach(function(result) { %>
    <%= console.log(data.weather) %>
      <%= result.description %>
  <% }) %>
  <% let tempInFahrenheit = (data.main.temp * 9/5) - 459.67; %>
  <%=Math.floor(tempInFahrenheit)%> degrees outside.
<% } %>
</p>
<div id="map"></div>
<a href="/">Back</a>

<%- include ("./partials/footer") %>
```

The 404 is expected if you misspell the city name. Also, the input Laos is throwing 404 because it is a country name.

Comment: Hmm, tried that.  Still no luck.  In the terminal, random elements keep coming back as not defined.   In the "if" statement I tried a few different conditions (result), (data), (data.weather).

Comment: @jpaulMolnar You should be able to resolve it with the same idea. Every time you try to access a property of an undefined variable, you will be getting an error. For example, `data.main.temp` will throw an error if `data` is not defined. So simply put another conditional check before using that variable. Try again with my edited code snippet.

Comment: Tried that second snippet as well and still the problem persists.  I'm also getting a TypeError: req.next is not a function message, although I have on idea what that means.  There seems to be a problem passing the data object to the results.ejs page.

Comment: I was actually able to make a little headway.  I changed my get request over to the request-promise format and that seems to stop the server from crashing with spelling mistakes.  However if the input is incorrectly spelled it will just time out.

Comment: I might be able to help if you update your question and add the most recent version of your code. Also include the full error message.